# Pass json object from android(java) to javascript in Webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, webview

I am working on an Android Webview Application.I need to call a function from Javascript and the Java function should return a JSON object.If the there is only one value in my JSON object i could access it from Javascript.But if there is more than one i get the value `undefined`.

ex: In  **Java** method

```
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
ob.put("hello","hai");
return String.valueOf(ob);
```

In **Javascript**

```
data = app.getValue();
obj = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(obj.hello);
```

**The above code works Fine but,**

In  **Java** method

```
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
ob.put("hello","hai");
ob.put("abc","xyz");
return String.valueOf(ob);
```

In **Javascript**

```
data = app.getValue();
obj = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(obj.hello); <- doesn't work
console.log(obj[0].hello); <- doesn't work
```

Comment: Could you try replace String.valueOf() with [toString](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()) method

Comment: It worked..Thanks :)

Comment: Please right an answer so we know it's solved

Comment: @slesh Is there any way to access values by using indices? like obj[0],obj[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @slesh,I finally able to solve the problem
I changed from `return String.valueOf(ob);` to this   `return obj.toString();`

Comment: When you write ***obj[0]*** you access to the first item of the array, so to be such syntax was working this ***obj*** should be an array.